# Get jobs count without using group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have the following code to calculate the number of jobs of a certain client.

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT= 'Y' then 1 end) as JOBS_COUNT
FROM CLIENTS
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
```

Nevertheless, to complete this I need to use a group by at the end, what I'm looking for is a query that counts the flags CURRENT, within a partition, so I do no have to use a group by at the end, is that possible?

Comment: Use windows function to partition the result and get the distinct

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a row_number() over the partition and select rn =1 to avoid duplicates over the partition using a derived table as well.
The solution I added gets distinct partitions with count.  If you need more help, let me know.

```
SELECT Distinct CLIENT_ID,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT= 'Y' then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY ep.CLIENT_ID) as 
 jos_count as JOBS_COUNT
FROM CLIENTS
```

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT = 'Y' then 1 end) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID) as JOBS_COUNT
FROM CLIENTS;
```

This seems like an odd request, because you return multiple rows per `CLIENT_ID`.  However, that appears to be what you are asking for.